# List render in react native show on the same line

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, styles

I have a list rendered in react native, but I don't know why the list appear on the same line. Currently all the list is displayed on just one line, and not on differents lines

```
<TouchableOpacity key={key} style={LoginStyle.imagenes}>
    <Image
        style={LoginStyle.imagenCofre}
        width={100}
        height={100}
        source={{uri: e.imagen }}
    />
    <Text>{e.texto}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

---

Here's my style content:

```
contenedorCofres:{
     flexDirection: 'row', 

     flex: 1, 
},
imagenes:{
    width:30,
    height:30
},
imagenCofre:{
    width:30,
    height:30,

    flex: 1 
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/B1G7J2Ndz

Comment: Can you show us your complete code? We don't see your list in the snippets above

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers thanks for your help, i just add the codepen

Comment: Actually you don't use a ListView. Have a look her: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: You are using `flexDirection: row` in your parent container, which renders it on single line

Comment: @PritishVaidya then wath do you recommend use?

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ , just remove `flexDirection: 'row'`, and it will align itself to `column` by default